# XY coordinates efficient way to copy

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, georeferencing, pdf, xy

I get XY coordinates of point features delivered to me in PDF format, this means that to bring them into ArcGIS I manually have to enter them first into an excel spreadsheet.

Is it possible to copy the coordinates straight from pdf?

Comment: There are lots of tools to convert PDF to HTML or text available, online, free or paid. But they won't help you if the data is scanned, or the author has not allowed the copying of the content.

Comment: you can try this free tool https://tabula.technology/

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably discovered, copying tables from a PDF and pasting into a spreadsheet doesn't work very reliably; Libreoffice seems to have a better chance of parsing the table and creating a usable spreadsheet (that you could then save as CSV or open directly in QGIS).

More reliably, use [SmallPDF.com](http://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-excel)'s PDF to Excel converter (or PDF to Word for documents that have more than tables).